# android osmdroid vector maps

Tags: android, maps, openstreetmap, osmdroid

In my android project I want to have offline maps. with tiles my map takes 500 mb of space and I also want to search address on the map offline. 
I think the only way to decrease size and make it possible to search , vector maps. How can I use vector maps in OSMdroid ? Where can I get vector maps ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK most would use Mapsforge in your case: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks#Widgets

Answer (score 0):

For reducing the size of tiles you can zip your tiles and copy it to osmdroid folder in sdcard (You must keep current structures of tiles folder).

But you can use KML files in osmdroid as a data source for handling features with
[OSMBonusPack](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/) to load kml file in osmdroid map.

Also see [this example](http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_3).

Comment: I use zip file and it is huge. I saw the KML example , and where can I get KML map for my country or for any region ?

Comment: This is another question. You should ask this in http://opendata.stackexchange.com/ or http://gis.stackexchange.com/